# Webdriver.Quit() is causing firefox is stopped working in c# selenium automation

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium's driver.Quit() for closing the firefox using C# code. It is closing  the firefox but saying Firefox is stopped working.

So what may be the issue there with code or any other way to quit the firefox using code. Please suggest.

Logs:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: firefox.exe
  Application Version:  50.1.0.6186
  Application Timestamp:    5849ff9c
  Fault Module Name:    mozglue.dll
  Fault Module Version: 50.1.0.6186
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5849ff8b
  Exception Code:   80000003
  Exception Offset: 0000ec79
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: hi, what is your Selenium version?

Comment: I am using Selenium version 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about C# selenium. But in Python we use webdriver.close() and can use webdriver.quit()

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue with Selenium 3.0 at the moment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/173

If you absolutely need to use firefox in your tests, you can always end the process instead of quitting properly. I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach but until the issue is officially resolved this may be the best option at the moment to avoid the crash window:

```
string sProcessName = "firefox";

if (oBrowser.Capabilities.BrowserName == sProcessName) {
    // Special fix for firefox because of issue https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/173
    // Kills all firefox processes

    Process[] oProccesses = null;
    bool bFound = true;

    while (bFound == true) {
        bFound = false;
        oProccesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcessName);

        foreach (Process oCurrentProcess in oProccesses) {
            bFound = true;
            oCurrentProcess.Kill();
        }
    }
} else {
    // Close browser properly

    oBrowser.Quit();
}
```